# simple select within stored procedure

Tags: oracle, select, stored-procedures

I have this SP, and the select statement it doesn't work. It always says me an `INTO` expected.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETDATANEWSP (
  P_ID NUMBER
  )
AS
BEGIN
 SELECT ID as d_id,
       USUARIO as d_usuario,
       SPAEJECUTAR as d_spaejecutar,
       NOMBREREPORTE as d_nombrereporte,
       XMLPARAMETROS as d_xmlparam,
       FECHA as d_fecha
  FROM REPORTESBATCH WHERE ID = P_ID;
END;
/
```

I'd like to know where or what is wrong, and even if there're different ways to do it also.

Comment: Like the error says, you [need to select into something](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm) in a PL/SQL context. Either five local variables  or a record type. As long as you will get a single row back from the query. What do you intend to do with the values once you have them? (Also, [this has been asked many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+pls-00428))

Answer (score 0):

as the error message says you need a variable/record or array to put the results of the query into.  Your code should be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETDATANEWSP (   P_ID NUMBER   ) AS 
v_row REPORTESBATCH %ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN  SELECT ID as d_id,
       USUARIO as d_usuario,
       SPAEJECUTAR as d_spaejecutar,
       NOMBREREPORTE as d_nombrereporte,
       XMLPARAMETROS as d_xmlparam,
       FECHA as d_fecha  
       INTO v_row   
       FROM REPORTESBATCH 
       WHERE ID = P_ID; END;
```

but if you need to do further processing you might find it visually easier to work with a variable for each item like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETDATANEWSP (   P_ID NUMBER   ) AS 
--declare each variable here 
   BEGIN  SELECT ID as d_id,
           USUARIO as d_usuario,
           SPAEJECUTAR as d_spaejecutar,
           NOMBREREPORTE as d_nombrereporte,
           XMLPARAMETROS as d_xmlparam,
           FECHA as d_fecha   
           INTO v_id, v_d_usuario, v_d_spaejecutar,
           v_d_nombrereporte,v_d_xmlparam, v_d_fecha
           FROM REPORTESBATCH 
           WHERE ID = P_ID; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is this one.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETDATANEWSP (
      P_ID NUMBER,
      P_CURSOR OUT SYSREFCURSOR 
     )
    AS
    BEGIN
     OPEN P_CURSOR FOR
     SELECT ID as d_id,
           USUARIO as d_usuario,
           SPAEJECUTAR as d_spaejecutar,
           NOMBREREPORTE as d_nombrereporte,
           XMLPARAMETROS as d_xmlparam,
           FECHA as d_fecha
      FROM REPORTESBATCH WHERE ID = P_ID;
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
    END;

/
```

Comment: @kevinsky I know I didn't clear that, but it was the better solution. When I tried with the 'INTO', it didn't work.